# Reading bytes from /dev/random fails

Tags: c, macos, posix, stdio

I have a piece of code written in POSIX compliant C and it doesn't seem to work correctly. The goal is to read from /dev/random, the interface to the Linux/BSD/Darwin kernel's random number generator and output the written byte to a file. I'm not quite sure what I'm overlooking as I'm sure I've covered every ground. Anyway, here it is:

```
int incinerate(int number, const char * names[]) {
if (number == 0) {
    // this shouldn't happen, but if it does, print an error message
    fprintf(stderr, "Incinerator: no input files\n");
    return 1;
}

// declare some stuff we'll be using
long long lengthOfFile = 0, bytesRead = 0;
int myRandomInteger;

// open the random file block device
int zeroPoint = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY);

// start looping through and nuking files
for (int i = 1; i < number; i++) {
    int filePoint = open(names[i], O_WRONLY);

    // get the file size
    struct stat st;
    stat(names[i], &st);
    lengthOfFile = st.st_size;
    printf("The size of the file is %llu bytes.\n", lengthOfFile);

    while (lengthOfFile != bytesRead) {
        read(zeroPoint, &myRandomInteger, sizeof myRandomInteger);
        write(filePoint, (const void*) myRandomInteger, sizeof(myRandomInteger));
        bytesRead++;
    }

    close(filePoint);
}

return 0;
}
```

Any ideas? This is being developed on OS X but I see no reason why it shouldn't also work on Linux or FreeBSD.

If it helps, I've included the following headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
```

Comment: What does not work - what are the errors?

Comment: Add error checking to those `read()`/`write()` calls and report errors using `strerror(errno)`.  Plus you are not reading/writing 'bytes', you are reading/writing `int`s.

Comment: It simply silently fails... the OS reports the file size is the same and when I open the file nothing was altered. I tested this on a text file so I would be able to detect changes.

Comment: It's silently fails cos you made it silent...  Also `sizeof myRandomInteger` isn't legal, so that code can't compile.

Comment: @trojanfoe: The code compiles without any issues or warnings reported by the compiler.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Expressions don't need brackets for sizeof, only types.

Comment: Maybe it is not doing what you expect because you ignore the first file in the list? You start your loop at `i=1` so you are ignoring `names[0]`. Like others have said, you need to add error checking to your `open()`, your `read()`, your `write()` and so on if you want to have any hope of knowing what's going on.

Comment: To add my 2 cents: Inside your while loop you read and write data in chunks of 4 Bytes (I assume that `sizeof(int)==4`) but increment `bytesRead` only by 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
write(filePoint, (const void*) myRandomInteger, sizeof(myRandomInteger));
```

you surely meant to write

```
write(filePoint, (const void*) &myRandomInteger, sizeof(myRandomInteger));
```

didn't you? If you use the random bytes read from `/dev/random` as a pointer, you're almost certain to encounter a segfault sooner or later.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I applied all of your suggestions and the code is now working! Thanks a million!